# How to display the sum of three ratingbar?

Tags: android

I'm working on a small rating application,I have three rating bars. I want, when I choose each rating bar it appears in an EditText then all the result is calculated and the sum is displayed in a TextView. Each time the values are changed, the sum is updated.  Unfortunately, I'm not able to display the sum.

Can someone help me please.

Here is my code:

```
 ratingBarHeures.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new 
    RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, 
     boolean fromUser) {
            myResult.setText("Resultat : " + rating);
     }
    });
    ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new 
    RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating1, 
    boolean fromUser) {
            myResult1.setText("Resultat : " + rating1);
     }
    });

    ratingBarSerice.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new 
    RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating2, 
    boolean fromUser) {
            String.valueOf(rating2);
            myResult2.setText("Resultat : " + rating2);
        }
    });

}
public void rateMe(View view){
    final String nbr_heure,donne,service;
    nbr_heure=String.valueOf(ratingBarHeures.getRating());
    donne = String.valueOf(ratingBar.getRating());
    service = String.valueOf(ratingBarSerice.getRating());
    StringRequest stringRequest =new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, 
    service_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
  Toast.makeText(getApplication(),response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("Response", response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
   Toast.makeText(AvisActivity.this,error+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }}){
      @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("qualité", String.valueOf(donne));
            params.put("nbr_heure", nbr_heure);
            params.put("service",String.valueOf(service));
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `OnRatingBarChangeListener` for each rating bar set its own `TextView` with the rating selected and as well get the total rating already set in the total rating `TextView`, add the new rating and set it again. Assuming you have a sum `TextView` initialized as RatingSum with default text `Resultat: 0`;

```
ratingBarHeures.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new 
    RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
            myResult.setText("Resultat : " + rating);
            float totalRating = Float.parseFloat(RatingSum.getText().toString().split(": ")[1]);
            float newTotalRating = rating + totalRating
            RatingSum.setText("Resultat: "+String.valueOf(newTotalRating));

        }
});

ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new 
    RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating1, boolean fromUser) {
            myResult1.setText("Resultat : " + rating1);
            float totalRating = Float.parseFloat(RatingSum.getText().toString().split(": ")[1]);
            float newTotalRating = rating + totalRating
            RatingSum.setText("Resultat: "+String.valueOf(newTotalRating));
        }
});

ratingBarSerice.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new 
     RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
         @Override
         public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating2, boolean fromUser) {
             myResult2.setText("Resultat : " + rating2);
             float totalRating = Float.parseFloat(RatingSum.getText().toString().split(": ")[1]);
             float newTotalRating = rating + totalRating
             RatingSum.setText("Resultat: "+String.valueOf(newTotalRating));
         }
});
```

Comment: an error here ' float totalRating = Float.parseFloat(note.getText().toString().split(": ")[1]);'  do not correct

Comment: What error did you get? Note the assumption that you have a `TextView` to show the total rating with an initial text `Resultat: 0`. So the code strips off the `Resultat: ` to get the value.